# How to get a list of URLs of all included/used files of webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to get a list of all URLs that a website uses, includes or could use. For example the background image(es), Javascripts, css, images and so on.

Css and Javascripts would be ok for the beginning. I could get the images with parsing the DOM. But I don't know an easy way for getting all Javascript-File URLs. Or backround images that are currently not used but could be loaded via css include directions.

Is there a way to get a list of all these media with jquery or plain javascript?

Comment: How much/any of this loaded with ajax?

Comment: It depends, it is for an extension Javascript addon users can add to their sites. So I don't have any exact numbers. But Ajax loads could be possible but should be rare I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [.map( callback )](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can get a list of all URLs contained in a page by selecting:

```
$('[src], [href]')
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  var importCss = $('style').text().split('\n').filter(function(element, index, array) {
    return (element.indexOf('@import') > -1) || (element.indexOf('url(') > -1);
  }).map(function(element, index, array) {
    if (element.indexOf('@import') > -1) {
      return 'Imported css: ' + element.replace(/([ ';]|@import)/g, '');
    }
    return 'Imported image: ' + element.replace(/([ ';()'"]|background-image:.*url)/g, '');
  });
  var list = $('[src], [href]').map(function(index, element) {
    return  this.tagName + ': ' + (this.src || this.href);
  }).get();

  console.log(importCss.join(',\n') + '\n'+ list.join(',\n'));

});
```

```css
@import 'custom.css';
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
```

Comment: That is very good so far. But do you know a way to get also the css @import instructions or background image urls from the css files?

Comment: @Chris I'm obliged to remove old comments. Sorry. It's a rule on SO to be short. Yes, for the base tag you have it into the list  array variable and you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

yes:

```
var urls= [];
for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;)
    if (document.links[i].hostname===location.hostname)
        urls.push(document.links[i].href);
console.log(urls);
```

this will show you all links...

Comment: But using this I only get a list of all links. No included images, css, javascripts. Or is there something I overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to get a list of all URLs that a website uses, includes or could use. For example the background image(es), Javascripts, css, images and so on.

That's a pretty tall order (to get correct).

All resources that are *actually loaded* could be obtained by abusing [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). This allows you to intercept any and all network requests that are made on behalf of the document. Note that this is a new API with [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers). If you can live with the caveat that the ServiceWorker is only activated on the *second* visit to the document and SW , this is definitely the thing you want to look into.

If ServiceWorker is not an option, you'll have to scrape the DOM and the [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model).

When scraping the DOM, look for [these elements/attribute](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/blob/gh-pages/src/URI.js#L240-L255) (not sure if you're interested in `<blockquote cite="<url>"` and `<form action="<url>">`). You'll also have to examine *every* DOM element's `style` attribute, as `background-image: url('<url>');` (among others) might be hidden there.

When scraping the CSSOM (for content of `<style>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">`), note that Same Origin Policy restrictions apply and you'll not be able to access the styles loaded from different domains. Filtering for `CSSImportRule` and `CSSFontFaceRule` should be straight forward. As for the other styles, you'll have to walk the `CSSRuleList` and look for [`<url>`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#urls) values.

Note that URLs may be relative. Everything you pulled from the DOM is relative to the document, or its [`<base href="<url>"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). Everything you pulled from the CSSOM is relative to the given StyleSheet's href (every element in [StyleSheetList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StylesheetList) will have a different URL).

> But I don't know an easy way for getting all Javascript-File URLs.

If "Javascript-File URLs" refers to anything other than `<script src="<url>">` please explain what you mean. You won't be able to identify all URLs constructed by JavaScript without actually executing the scripts. And even then it's a nightmare.

> Or backround images that are currently not used but could be loaded via css include directions.

The CSSOM would give you access to that information.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating this. Other Javascript-URLs could be document.write statements after my own scripts is execured: document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="foo.js">\x3C/script>'); I think you are right: It is a nightmare.